# Why aren't my tags updating when a user clicks on the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't seem to see what I'm missing in my conditional statements. When the button's are clicked on the page the `textContent` isn't updating.

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector('.btn1');
const btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn2');
const btn3 = document.querySelector('.btn3');
const playerChoice = [btn1, btn2, btn3];
const computerChoice = ['Lapis','Payrus','Scalpellus']


// Game options rock[0] , paper[1] , scissors[2]
// Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus;

  const startGame = () => {
    
    playerChoice.forEach(options => {
            options.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
            
          const rantInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
          const pcOptions = computerChoice[rantInt];

            //Callback to compare choices
            compareChoices(this.innerHTML, pcOptions);
        });
       
    });
  };
   startGame();

  const compareChoices = (player, computer) => {

    const result = document.querySelector('.winner');
    
      if ( player === computer) {
          result.textContent = 'TIE'
      } 
      else if (player == 'Lapis' && computer == 'Scalpellus') {
        result.textContent = 'Player won! Lapis beats Scalpellus.';
      }
        else if (computer == 'Lapis' && player == 'Scalpellus') {
          result.textContent = 'Computer won! Lapis beats Scalpellus';
        } 
    else {
      return;
    }
      
  };
```

```css
text-align: { 
center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #E44949;
}

.btn1 {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FA9696;
}

.btn2 {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FA9696;
}

.btn3 {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FA9696;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&family=Rubik:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
</style>

<h1>Let's play! Click on the buttons.</h1>

<h1>
   <button class="btn1">Lapis</button> 
    <button class="btn2">Papyrus</button>  
    <button class="btn3">Scalpellus</button>
  </h1>

  <h2 class="winner"></h2>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's my fault. Forgot to switch it back. But in the code that I have is still isn't working.

Comment: You compare the `.innerHTML` (which are "Lapis", "Papyrus" and "Scalpellus") against "rock", "paper" and "scissors"?

Comment: That worked. I had that array as a comment. Must have slipt on me.

Answer (score -1):

arrow function changes the value of `this`.
To make `this` refer to the element (button) use normal function:

```js
playerChoice.forEach(function(options) {
  options.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const rantInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    const pcOptions = computerChoice[rantInt];

    //Callback to compare choices
    compareChoices(this.innerHTML, pcOptions);
  });
});
```

Comment: The `this` is inside of the anonymous function expression passed to the `options.addEventListener()`. That's not an arrow function.